# how to mirror a div in css in chat ui

Tags: html, css

i am trying to build a chat ui , in which i want to mirror the div and place it in right , please see the below image, just like chat ui , i want to place send message in right , i can do by position but i want to flip just like receive message, but different position..

[current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IxdJ.jpg)

code

```
.private_chat_receive_div {
margin: 0.5vw;
background-color: #282835;
padding: 1vw;
width: fit-content;
border-radius: 0.8vw;
position: relative;
left: 0.5vw;
top: 1vw;
}

.private_chat_send_div {
margin: 0.5vw;
background-color: #282835;
padding: 1vw;
width: fit-content;
border-radius: 0.8vw;
position: relative;
left: 0.5vw;
top: 1vw;
}
#private_chat_receive_message {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.35vw;
max-width: 15vw;
font-size: 1.3vw;
}
#private_chat_send_message {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.35vw;
max-width: 15vw;
}
```

Comment: you can use flexbox or grid layout for this

Comment: Use CSS flex property to align receive message to flex start and send message to flex end

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the divs into a container, and add `display: flex;` to it. Then you can use `align-self: flex-end;` property on `.private_chat_send_div`.

```css
.container{
  width: 99vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.private_chat_receive_div {
  margin: 0.5vw;
  background-color: #282835;
  padding: 1vw;
  width: 15vw;
  border-radius: 0.8vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 1vw;
  left: 0.5vw;
  color: #fff;
}

.private_chat_send_div {
  margin: 0.5vw;
  background-color: #282835;
  padding: 1vw;
  width: 15vw;
  border-radius: 0.8vw;
  position: relative;
  right: 0.5vw;
  top: 1vw;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 0.5vw;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#private_chat_receive_message {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.35vw;
  max-width: 15vw;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}

#private_chat_send_message {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.35vw;
  max-width: 15vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="private_chat_receive_div">
    <span id="private_chat_receive_message">Receive</span>
  </div>

  <div class="private_chat_send_div">
    <span id="private_chat_send_message">Send</span>
  </div>
</div>
```